# Write environment variable to a file in Gradle

Tags: gradle, environment-variables

I need to save an environment variable into a file in Gradle.

I have tried to use the below code, but it just writes `null`.

```
def file1 = new File('.test')
```

`file1 << System.getenv(“MY_PW")`

Also it is required to check, if any contents previously exist, then it should replace with the System.getenv(“MY_PW").

Any help please, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If `null` is written to the file, then the environment variable seems to not be defined, because the code is fine.

To replace the contents instead of appending to it, use `file1.text = ...` instead of `file1 << ...`.

Comment: Tried with other env variable, but still it writes null.

Comment: Maybe try with `System.getenv().keySet()` to get all valid keys and get an idea on what is wrong.